# Problems while applying an svn patch to a mercurial repository

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisesvn

Patch file is made with TortoiseSVN-> Create Patch...

Attempting to import patch into the mercurial repository using `hg import patchfile`.

There seem to be problems with how hg looks for files referenced in the patch file:

```
unable to find 'gui/gui/RemoteFramework.cpp' for patching
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file gui/gui/RemoteFramwork.cpp.rej
```

This seems to be an issue of where the patch was made in terms of directories and where it should be applied. I have tried playing with the --base option for hg import, but haven't gotten anywhere just yet.

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you need to do `hg import --strip 0 patchfile` since Subversion doesn't include any prefix on the file path. `--base` specifies where it should search for files, and `--strip` says how many (default 1) path elements to ignore on the beginning of the diff headers.

Comment: If you use the "patch" synonym to import, and the short form of --strip, it looks a lot like using plain old patch:

hg patch -p0 patchfile

Comment: Thank you! This helped me as well. BTW, this very thing works for CVS patches like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem moving my project, CartoType, from Subversion to Mercurial. I had the Subversion stuff checked out to C:\CartoType, and a clone of the Mercurial repository in C:\CartoType-mercurial.

I used TortoiseSVN to create unified diff files, and found that it was using paths like C:/CartoType/src/main/router/cartotype_router.h in them. Running hg patch in C:\CartoType-mercurial, I found the right thing to do was to strip two elements from the path, thus:

```
hg patch -p2 c:\temp\patch1982.diff
```

The other important thing I needed to do was replace the 'Index' lines in the diff file with check-in comments, because that's where hg patch gets them from. So in this example I had to change the first line of my diff file from

```
Index: C:/CartoType/src/main/router/cartotype_router.h
```

to

```
Added an optional parameter to NewRoadOrWalkingRouter... (etc.)
```

If there are multiple Index lines in the diff file, change them all to the same check-in comment.